# Incorrect runtime version of NUnit referenced when installing from NuGet

Tags: nunit, nuget

I have just updated my NUnit NuGet reference and my project now appears to reference an NUnit dll built for .NET 1.1. I am running .NET 4.0 and hence this is causing compilation errors.

Why might the wrong DLL be referenced here?

I'm sorry for the lack of additional information, but this is all I have to go on at the moment. I will update the question if I find out more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a packaging problem with NUnit which is being fixed.